# How can i monitor usage of each iot device separately on aws using rules engine? Is there any other way to do the same?

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, iot, rule-engine, aws-iot

we are currently using aws iot messaging and shadow service, and the total usage can be monitored using cloudwatch, but i want to monitor usage per device.i am new to aws so the only way i can think of is to make a rule which gets triggered every time message is published, extract the thing id from the topic and increase the counter for that thing in dynamodb. How can i do it step by step? i have followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-ddb-rule.html) tutorial but it doesn't work. is there any better way  to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into some IoT analytics software. There is a lot of companies which do this type of thing. You could even build your own with open source software, but it would require you learn and stand up ELK, along with your own instrumentation. I work for a company (AppDynamics) which offers these capabilities along with other application performance monitoring. Have a look at our IoT solution.